# Why do we need a function plugin when we write a method plugin

Tags: jquery

I am a JQuery newbie and I came across this jquery plugin sample code when I was reading a Jquery book.

```
//adding a function to JQuery object
jQuery.slowEach = function( array, interval, callback ) {
    if( ! array.length ) return;
    var i = 0;
    next();
    function next() {
        if( callback.call( array[i], i, array[i] ) !== false )
            if( ++i < array.length )
                setTimeout( next, interval );
    }
    return array;
};

//attaching a new method .slowEach()
jQuery.fn.slowEach = function( interval, callback ) {
    return jQuery.slowEach( this, interval, callback );
};

// Show an element every half second
$('.reveal').slowEach( 500, function() {
    $(this).show();
})
```

I just want to know if it's necessary to write the function plugin when I'm writing such method plugin, and whats the significance? If not, can I write the whole thing in the jQuery.fn.slowEach method without the function plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not wrong, writing your function/method in `jQuery.fn`, you will be able to use it over all jQuery objects, because `.fn` is some kind of shortcut to the `prototype` of jQuery. You could do it, but you will need to change some things in the original code (e.g you will need to use `this` as the `array` variable). In this way, you will be able to do this:

```
//select a DOM element and apply the plugin on it
$('.reveal').slowEach( 500, function() {
   $(this).show();
});
```

Writing the plugin into `jQuery.yourplugin` makes it accessible without having a jQuery element. This means that you will be able to do something like this:

```
//use it without doing it over a jQuery element
var ar = [1,2,3];
jQuery.slowEach(ar,500,function(){
   alert("hey");
});
```

Comment: Nice answer. To elaborate; essentially you don't need `jQuery.slowEach`, and instead it's easier to simply write against the prototype, referencing `this`. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: it work perfectly when I combined the function into the method(i know its not necessary, but i just want to prove it works)

for people who want to know more, when you put the function back to the method, you need to put 'this' into a variable and use the variable as 'this' frist otherwise it wont work.